# RegEx for Alias in apache 2.4 httpd conf file

Tags: regex, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have an Alias as below in my apache 2.4 httpd conf file
For every release we'll update the version number and am trying to use a regex to catch the changes instead of manually changing the version number every time

For example our current version is Passport14100(14 is the year number and 1 is for first release in 2014) our next release in this year will be Passport14200( 2nd release in 2014) and our first release in 2015 will be Passport15100

This is how my httpd conf file looks like now

```
Alias /Passport14100 C:/Passport/tomcat/webapps/?Passport
<Directory C:/Datacert/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport>
    Require all denied
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|jpg|png|js|css|ico)$">
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
</Directory>
```

Am wondering is there a way to alias with a regex so that it catches Passport[\d{5}]?

I am new to the Regularexpressions, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try [AliasMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch)